# File not being synced from container to host in docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

So, I am using `docker-compose` to run a simple flask app alongside nginx.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on:
            - flask
        networks:
            - my-network
    flask:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: webapp-flask
        container_name: flask
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./
              target: /app
            - type: bind
              source: ./users.json
              target: /app/users.json
        networks:
            my-network:
                aliases:
                    - flask-app
        ports:
            - 8080:5000
networks:
    my-network:
```

In the `volumes:` section I am trying to bind the current host directory to `/app` directory on the host, also the `users.json` file (which I want to be synced)

Here is the `Dockerfile` for the flask:

```
FROM python:3
RUN pip install flask flask-restful
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python app/app.py
```

The `app.py` makes changes to the `users.json` as requests are made. Everything is working fine except the fact that when the `users.json` file is updated on the container (via a request, let's say), the update does not reflect on my host machine.

Just for information, I am using Windows and the Docker Toolbox.
Is there anything special that I need to do to bind users.json between host and my container?

**EDIT:** This problem was due to my own stupidity, first problem is that in my `Dockerfile` I use the `python:3` image and then in my `docker-compose.yml` I again used a new image of `webapp-flask`. I don't know why this wasn't conflicting in the first place, but apparently then real problem was that whenever I was running `docker-compose up` it used a cached build of my older files and never rebuilt the container. I figured this out when I made changes to my `app.py` and they didn't take effect when running the whole thing. So, all I did was to remove the older containers, remove the line where it specifies the image in the `docker-compose.yml` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

[Akhand Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8466559/akhand-mishra),

Few questions:

- Where does the `users.json` file live on your host system? Is it outside of your application directory? (If not, then)
- Is there any reason that the volume configuration cannot be simplified to bind the entire application directory to the container? It appears you are already doing this, but also binding the `users.json` file as an additional target.

My recommendation would be to possibly make an additional `/data/` directory on your host machine which could be used to house the `users.json` file. So, something like this in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
flask:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: webapp-flask
    container_name: flask
    volumes:
        - .:/app/
        - .:/data/
    networks:
        my-network:
            aliases:
                - flask-app
    ports:
        - 8080:5000
```

I'm unsure if volumes can be mounted to an explicit singular file via compose, and suspect that it may need to be an entire directory that is called out in the volume yaml keys.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried creating a separate directory but it didn't work. As for your questions: users.json lives in the same dir as the app.py (or the current dir that is being loaded on to the docker). I was earlier applying only the first bind, but then it didn't work, so I tried specifying the file.

Comment: Alright, so I solved it, it was due to my own stupidity